# How to use user wildcard in a custom path?

Tags: 7, routes

I set the path alias for User entity to *consultant/[user:name]*. I need to use *consultant/[user:name]/job* as route and I am using the following code for a `hook_menu()` implementation.

```php
$items['user/%user/job'] = array(
  'title' => 'Apply for job',
  'page callback' => 'job_application_page',   
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'file' => 'job.pages.inc',
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

The route should match, for a user whose username is Joan, the /consultant/joan/job path. That does not work and it returns a 404 error.

What should I correct in the code to make it work?

Comment: What do you mean by **this is not working**? Any error message? Have you followed https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x#sec_path_wildcards? As I don't see any `'page arguments' => array(1)` being passed.

Comment: Is `%user` an actual user object? Or is consultant a node type?

Answer (score 3):

You've picked `user_load` as your wildcard's load function - that takes an ID, and loads a user object. Your requirement is to load by username, which will work differently.

A function ending with `_load` doesn't exist for that, so you'll have to create your own:

```
$items['user/%MYMODULE_user_name/job'] = array(
...

function MYMODULE_user_name_load($name) {
  return user_load_by_name($name);
}
```